# error: Regular expressions are not functional, you need g++ 4.9.0 or greater

Tags: ubuntu, g++

When I install the [stacks](http://catchenlab.life.illinois.edu/stacks/) in my Ubuntu 16.04:

```
...
checking for sqrt... no
checking for functional regular expressions... configure: error: Regular expressions are not functional, you need g++ 4.9.0 or greater.
```

I check my g++ there is `8.2.0`:

```
suser@suser-S2600CP[stacks-1.48] g++ -v                           [10:34] 
using specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/8.2.0/lto-wrapper
target：x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
configure：../configure -enable-checking=release -enable-languages=c,c++ -disable-multilib
threading model：posix
gcc version 8.2.0 (GCC)
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. I was able to build stacks using `gcc8` on Ubuntu 18.10 with no issues. Is your `gcc` and `g++` source compiled or installed via `apt`? Add the output of ls -l $(which gcc) to your question.

Comment: I use the `/usr/local/bin/gcc` gets the `gcc 8.2.0`.

Comment: From the output of `g++ -v`, it looks like you built it from source. Do you have the libraries appended to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: From the configuration options you posted it's clear that you haven't configured GCC with all the required libs . Look at my [configuration](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Dp3VXDJJsF/) and also [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9450422/11970791).